# Reasons for using 64bit floats instead of 32 bit floats

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing some analysis on ndarrays of around 10 million in length.

The source data numbers range from 1.00 to 1000.00, with 2 decimal places.

I have found that using 32bit floats, as well as being 50% as large, are about 30% faster when performing floating point arithmetic.

I am thinking of converting all my data to 32 bit. If I do that, am I likely to hit any problems in the future?

Edit:

Doing a few more tests on the code, if I use numba to iterate over this data, then the performance of 32 bits is little slower.

But if I use numpy and do a vectorised operation, 32 bits is a lot faster.

What could explain this?

```
from numba import autojit

@autojit( nopython=True )
def nsum( x ):
    r=0.0
    for i in range( x.shape[0] ):
        r+=x[i]
    return r

y64 = np.random.randn( 1e7 )
y32 = y64.astype( np.float32 )

%timeit nsum( y64 )
%timeit nsum( y32 )

> 100 loops, best of 3: 18.3 ms per loop
> 100 loops, best of 3: 18.6 ms per loop

%timeit y64**2
%timeit y32**2

> 10 loops, best of 3: 54.4 ms per loop
> 10 loops, best of 3: 27.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Only if you exceed the range of the `float`, or you find that `float` has insufficient precision.  Usually people pick double-precision floats because they need 15 decimal places of precision.  Single-precision (what you're calling 32 bit float) gives you about 7 digits of precision.

Comment: The speedup you're seeing is probably due to the smaller size, once you factor in cache effects. I don't think 32 bit floats are inherently faster on modern hardware.

Comment: numpy uses [SSE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2) commands for many floating point operations, so for those `float32` will indeed be twice as fast as `float64`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with such a limited floating number subset perhaps you should consider to use integers instead ranging from 100 to 100000 to accommodate for the two decimal spaces.

ints are also 32 bits but with some advantages in terms of making simple operations much faster and without loosing precision.

It will depend on what you are going to do with those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The 32 bit floats will be lower precision, which may or may not be an issue for your application.

Because you have a fixed number of decimal places you might be better off switching to fixed-point math. You can store everything as integers, scaled up by a factor of 100. This means 12.34 would be stored as 1234. Your math will be precise (no floating-point error), and because it is all integers it should run even faster than the floating-point math. However, it does make things a little more complicated - you need to be aware of how the decimal point moves when multiplying and dividing.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use 64-bit floats in the event that you needed more precision.

Computers work by representing numbers as bits & bytes. In the case of float, some portion of the byte is for the whole number and some are for the fraction. Depending on what needs to be represented, the the decimal is moved (hence "floating point") therefore allowing for either higher whole numbers with less decimal precision or lower whole numbers with more decimal precisions.

If your range is 1 to 1000 with only two decimals, then even 32-bit float in is probably too much but assuming that is what your input function takes, then yes -- use 32 bit float unless you need very large numbers or decimal precisions.

*Source: I've attempted to simplify a complex comp-sci topic. More information can be found here, for one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point*